# Odd boot logo flash

Tags: release-hera

I have a dual boot and as you can see in this [video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aB8uc.jpg),  it flashes between the pc logo(HP) and elementary logo, I have just installed Hera and this wasn't a problem before on juno.
Does anyone have this problem or knows where I could report it(I couldn't find the corresponding repo on GitHub)?